# How to use dynamic variables like %variable% in php from text saved in database?

Tags: php, variables, tags

Now i understand i will get down vote or hate about this question but i can't find answer anywhere and maybe i am just using wrong words of search.

I need to make function that will email users when they posts expire on website and text from email will be stored in database and i've seen some others use variables like %username% to get proper username on user who will receive email, but i don't get it how to do it my self.

So example of email template would be this:

```
Dear %username%
Your post will expire in %expiration% days, if you wish to extend your post please login.
On your dashboard you can manage your posts.
```

Where `%username%` will be `$username` of each user who is author of that post.

So any suggestions how is this done, so i need to search and replace for specific tags like `%username%`,

Have to mention that email template text will be stored in database field.

Comment: <?php echo $username ?>

Comment: or $email  = str_replace('%%username%%',$username, $emailBody);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace` to search for the placeholders within your text, and replace the content with the variables you have suggested.

```
str_replace(array('%username', '%expiration%'), array($username, $expiration), $body);
```

The first 2 parameters of `str_replace` need to *align*:

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value
>   from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If
>   replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for
>   the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a
>   string, then this replacement string is used for every value of
>   search. The converse would not make sense, though.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Thanks, i will try this out, will this match multiple %username% in text. If i have %username% on beginning of the text and again on end of text?

Comment: Yup, `str_replace` will replace all instances of matches found with the variables passed. There's a fourth param to tell PHP how many matches it should replace.